# Public access declaration does not affect member function pointers?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer

I have an issue regarding access declarations under g++ (version 5.1).

```
class Base
{
public:
    void doStuff() {}
};

class Derived : private Base
{
public:
    // Using older access declaration (without using) shoots a warning
    // and results in the same compilation error
    using Base::doStuff;
};

template<class C, typename Func>
void exec(C *c, Func func)
{
    (c->*func)();
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    // Until here, everything compiles fine
    d.doStuff();
    // For some reason, I can't access the function pointer
    exec(&d,&Derived::doStuff);
}
```

g++ fails to compile the above code with:

> test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void exec(C*, Func) [with C = Derived; Func = void (Base::*)()]’:
>   test.cpp:24:27:   required from here
>   test.cpp:17:4: error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Derived’
>     (c->*func)();

Even when the function itself can be called (`d.doStuff();`) the pointer can't be used even though I declared the function as accessible from the outside.
Private inheritance is also important, to some extent, because the `Derived` class chooses to expose only a certain set of members from base(s) which are interface implementations IRL.

NB : this is a question about the language, not class design.

Comment: compile with clang++ :D

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard The program is wrong, clang should (and does) reject it also.

Comment: @Barry it was a joke :( and no clang++ with -std=c++11 compile it on my computer

Comment: @Barry So I get a question. Why does this compile with clang version 3.0-6.2 ?

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard Hm? [It doesn't compile on 3.6.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1c0eff4ad8375bf)

Comment: It still compile on my computer with my clang version :D

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard It's a bug. e.g. [19274](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19274)

Comment: thanks I'd knew that but it's always fun to find one :)

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard Compiles under VC12 as well, therefore standard-proof :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `&Derived::doStuff` isn't actually a pointer to a member of class `Derived`. From [expr.unary.op]:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*.
>   If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static or variant member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`,
>   the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`.

`doStuff` is not a member of `Derived`. It is a member of `Base`. Hence it has type pointer to member of `Base`, or `void (Base::*)()`. What the *using-declaration* does here is simply an aid to overload resolution, from [namespace.udecl]:

> For the purpose of overload resolution, the functions which are introduced by a *using-declaration* into a
>   derived class will be treated as though they were members of the derived class.

That's why `d.doStuff()` works. However, through the function pointer, you're trying to call a `Base` member function on a `Derived` object. There's no overload resolution here since you're using a function pointer directly, so the base class function would be inaccessible.

You might think you could just cast `&Derived::doStuff` to the "correct" type:

```
exec(&d, static_cast<void (Derived::*)()>(&Derived::doStuff));
```

But you can't do that either according to [conv.mem], since again `Base` is an inaccessible base of `Derived`:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `B` of type *cv* `T`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type *cv* `T`”, where `D` is a derived class (Clause 10) of `B`. If `B` is an
>   **inaccessible (Clause 11)**, ambiguous (10.2), or virtual (10.1) base class of `D`, or a base class of a virtual base
>   class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.

Comment: What about a C-cast ? Will it blend ?

Comment: Is there a solution? Can the member be called at all through a memberfunction-pointer?

Comment: @JorenHeit: Guess not

Comment: @Barry: You're getting really good at this [tag:language-lawyer]ing. Nice work.

Comment: @Quentin A C-cast would end up doing a `reinterpret_cast` - the result of that conversion is "unspecified." The only specified `reinterpret_cast`s for pointers-to-members are for converting to another type *and back*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Aw, thanks :) I guess I should add that tag then?

Comment: @JorenHeit Nope. Not with pointers to member functions. There's always `std::function<void()> f = [d]{ d->doStuff(); };`

Comment: @Barry Fair enough. Ugly, but fair :-)

Comment: @JorenHeit I guess another way of doing it is actually defining `Derived::doStuff` function which calls `Base::doStuff` , but it's ugly as well

Answer (score 3):

I guess the reason is that the member function is not really part of the derived class, but rather of the base class. This can be shown somehow empirically by inspecting the type of the member function pointer and comparing it with a pointer to the base member function:

```
cout << typeid(&Derived::doStuff).name() << endl
  << typeid(& Base::doStuff).name() << endl;
```

[Live here.](http://ideone.com/drOodA)

<s>I'm currently searching the standard for some background on this.</s>
Barry's answer holds the respective parts of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stardard [namespace.udecl]:

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.
>
> If a using-declaration names a constructor (3.4.3.1), it implicitly
>   declares a set of constructors in the class in which the
>   using-declaration appears (12.9); otherwise the name specified in a
>   using-declaration is a synonym for a set of declarations in another
>   namespace or class.

So you're just introducing `Base::doStuff` into the `Derived` region, it's still a member function of `Base`.

Then `exec` is instantiated as `exec<Derived, void (Base::*)()>`, but it can't cast a `Derived*` to `Base*` because of the private inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++11 Standard, §7.3.3 [namespace.udecl], 18:

```
class A
{
private:
    void f( char );
public:
    void f( int );
protected:
    void g();
};
class B : public A
{
    using A::f; // error: A::f(char) is inaccessible
public:
    using A::g;
    // B::g is a public synonym for A::g
};
```

Note the **B::g is a public synonym for A::g** part. When you take the address of `Derived::doStuff`, GCC is creating a pointer to member function of type `void(Base::*)()`, and the standard says it's doing well. So, I think the compile time error is fair.

Comment: Examples are not normative.